# How to stretch something in Unity without losing the aspect ratio?

Tags: c#, android, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game on Unity, and here is my question:
So in UI, when I set an object's (like the title) Rect Transform to stretch, it loses aspect ratio as I change the screen size. But when I don't put anything, it shows too little on my phone screen. What do I have to do so it doesn't lose the aspect ratio but still stretches it according to screen?

Answer (score 3):

I think what you're after is the [Aspect Ratio Fitter](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-AspectRatioFitter.html) component.

If you're trying to stretch the width to fit, then you'd use that component and set the **Aspect Mode** to **Width Controls Height**. Although, you'd need to work out the Aspect ratio you want to preserve (width/height).

There are some other Aspect Modes that might be worth taking a look at too, depending on how you need this to work - **Fit in Parent** being one that you could use to set the desired size in relation to a parent 'stretched' element, but keeping the aspect.

Comment: Hi, so that works for some things, thank you. But how can I do it to do things like texts, or the texts in buttons, etc.?

Comment: Also, is there a way to change the distance between them too? Because when I make the screen big, they just go through each other. Also when I make it smaller, they disappear because The width becomes negative.

Comment: @Flash In answer to your first question, the easiest option would be to use an image for the button (including the text), making sure that the resolution is enough to cater for the resize. For the second, I'd look at parenting them to another GameObject (with a Rect transform) and anchor them accordingly within to make sure they scale properly.

Comment: [Content Size Fitter](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-ContentSizeFitter.html)  is another option you could try.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **preserve aspect** for images. For texts, you can use **Best Fit** option in the inspector(also adjust the max size according to your need).

Answer (score 1):

make canvas  UI scale mode to  scale width screensize,
keep reference resolution as width *height..recommended to keep height width and height so that it fit to screen size center,if possible make panel as parent and create all gameobjects into that,set layout element min to max width and height

Comment: Haha, this was a really old question, thanks for answering tho. I found my solution.